# Electron text input read/write excel table

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel, electron

I´m new in programming and try to write a little tool for my work with electron.
it has some text input forms, and i want to collect the data from the input in an external excel table. It also should be able to search the table by tags for Data. is something like this possible? maybe someone have some docs for me to read about it.

thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO .. See if [this helps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNpFB8M1-dI) .. and .. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPfpqkWIA_E) .. You will find such other videos on youtube.